# Selenium Firefox Python: How to change download directory

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, python-behave

Hello :/ I am currently having trouble setting up the Download folder inside my project.

I'm using Mac, Pycharm CE, Selenium, Python, Behave, and Firefox (project requirements).

I tried this configuration [Python Selenium Firefox trouble with download directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71020401/python-selenium-firefox-trouble-with-download-directory) but I'm not sure which part did I do wrong. :/ The downloaded files still go to the default Downloads folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

@given("First step")
def step_impl(context):
    download_path = "/Users/this/is/the/absolute/path/downloads"
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", '2')
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_path)
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [how to switch download directory using selenium / firefox / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69974916/18680505) and [Downloading file to specified location with Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251803/18680505)

I suggest try changing

```py
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_path)
```

```py
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/Users/this/is/the/absolute/path/downloads')
```

if there are any spaces in the path then try

```py
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r'/Users/this/is/the\ space/absolute/path/downloads')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Thamognya! :) I changed the '2' to 2 as well. :) Btw, can we use relative path for this? Very useful when using CI. We're using docker.

Comment: Yes you can. Good luck.