# Selenium Firefox Python: Can we use relative path for downloads folder?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, download, python-behave

Hello :) This is related to my question here [Selenium Firefox Python: How to change download directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73648738/selenium-firefox-python-how-to-change-download-directory/73649005#73649005) thank you so much @Thamognya for the assistance.

Can we use a relative path for this? We're using Docker in CircleCI and it will be much more convenient to use the relative path `"ProjectTitle/downloads"` as path for download. Currently it's working for absolute path `/Users/this/is/the/absolute/path/downloads`. Is there a way to format it to work for relative path?

I tried this but it goes to the default Downloads folder:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"./downloads")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Even for this it goes to the default Downloads folder as well:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r'ProjectTitle/downloads')
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Other attempts:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "ProjectTitle/downloads")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Others:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"./downloads")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always convert a relative path to an absolute path.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311142/7058266)

Example:

```bash
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath("downloads_folder")
'/Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/downloads_folder'
```

Just convert the relative path to an absolute one before you use it.